# Declaration and definition in c++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I thought that every declaration is definition because there was the following quote from standard:

> A declaration is a definition unless ***%restrictions%***.

But my assumption is not true. Actually, applying ODR we have that the following program

```
class A;
class A;

int main(){ }
```

is ill-formed. But it is not true. I can't to find part of standard which permit to redeclare class type in the declarative region.

Comment: it's the other way around: any definition is a declaration

Comment: Many declarations, one definition. A definition is a declaration, but a declaration is not a definition. ODR is "one definition rule", and your example has two declarations. I'll leave it to someone else to explain from the standard...

Comment: I'm assuming this question is looking for standards-quotes, rather than an intuitive explanation of what declarations and definitions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quote (from C++11 3.1/2) answers the general question: "unless ***%restrictions%***" means that **not** every declaration is a definition. It's only a definition if none of those restrictions apply.

If you read those restrictions, you'll find

> it is a class name declaration

which answers your specific question. `class A;` is a class name declaration, but not a definition.

> I can't to find part of standard which permit to redeclare class type in the declarative region.

In general, you can declare an entity multiple times in the same declarative region, per C++11 3.3.1/4

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified name, they shall all refer to the same entity, or [other cases not relevant here]

Comment: Very interesting. But from the `Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified name, they shall all refer to the same entity` not implies that the set of declarations in the different declarative regions are refers to the distinct entities. Is it true at all?

Comment: @Dmitrii: No, just imagine `extern int a;` appearing twice in different regions. Still the same entity.

Comment: @Dmitrii: No, the rule doesn't imply its converse. It's usually the case that declarations in different regions refer to different entities; but not always, as in the case of an `extern` declaration inside a function referring to an entity in the surrounding namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "a declaration is a definition unless *%restrictions%*" is true. Have you read the *restrictions?* One of them is:

> it is a class name declaration

So `class A;` is not a definition because it is covered by one of the *restrictions.*

Just to clarify, quoting C++11, `[basic.def]§2`

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph **§** 3.1.2 states that

> **A declaration is a definition unless** it declares a function without
>   specifying the function’s body (8.4), it contains the extern specifier
>   (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification 25 (7.5) and neither an initializer
>   nor a function- body, it declares a static data member in a class
>   definition (9.2, 9.4), **it is a class name declaration** (9.1), it is an
>   opaque-enum-declaration (7.2), it is a template-parameter (14.1), it
>   is a parameter-declaration (8.3.5) in a function declarator that is
>   not the declarator of a function-definition, or it is a typedef
>   declaration (7.1.3), an alias-declaration (7.1.3), a using-declaration
>   (7.3.3), a static_assert-declaration (Clause 7), an attribute-
>   declaration (Clause 7), an empty-declaration (Clause 7), or a
>   using-directive (7.3.4).

Here

```
class A;
class A;

int main(){ }
```

it is a class name declaration.

In a statement

*A declaration is a definition unless %restrictions%.*

the *%restrictions%.* part is important.

---

> I thought that every declaration is definition

Let's prove that this is not true by a [contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction). So assume this is true. Then because we can have many redeclaration and every of this declarations is definition - we can have many redefinitions, right? But C++ Standard n3337 **§** 3.2/1 says

> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any
>   variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template.

what contradicts our assumption and thus this is not true that every declaration is definition.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case of:

Header1.h:

```
class A;

void function1(A * a);
```

Header2.h:

```
class A;

void function2(A * a);
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Header1.h"
#include "Header2.h"

#include "A.h" // header file defining A

int main()
{

}
```

what this really looks like to the compiler is:

```
class A;

void function1(A * a);

class A;

void function2(A * a);


class A { /* definition from A.h */ };


int main()
{

}
```